# Generic type handling in Avro encoder/decoder

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, avro

I am using `spring-intergration-kafka` to send and receive messages from kafka. The message object is based on a generic type. Base class looks like this

```
public abstract class AbstractMessage<T> implements Serializable {
 ...
}
```

I would like to be able to send and receive different implementations of this class. I am using the avro reflection based encoders and decoders

```
<bean id="kafkaMessageEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="com.....model.AbstractMessage" />
</bean>

<bean id="kafkaMessageDecoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaDecoder">
    <constructor-arg value="com.....model.AbstractMessage" />
</bean>
```

This fails with the error

> AvroTypeException: Unknown type: T

This makes sense because Avro cant figure out the generic type specified in the AbstractMessage class but then I decided to use custom encoder and decoder.

```
public class MessageEncoder implements Encoder<Object> {

@Override
public byte[] toBytes(Object object) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "".getBytes();
}

}

public class MessageDecoder implements Decoder<Object> {

@Override
public Object fromBytes(byte[] bs) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream bais = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bs));
        AbstractMessage<?> message = (AbstractMessage<?>) bais.readObject();
        return message;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And this works fine.

I guess my question is that I am not really doing anything special here. Why cant avro do the same thing and is there a different avro d/encoder that can serialize/deserialize my generic type objects.

Thanks